# input type checkbox cilck close all and click open all

Tags: javascript, php, html

When click at id"t1", id"t2" and id"t3" changes to id"t1"

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="t1" onchange="check_all()" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="t2" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="t3" checked>

<script>
  function check_all() {
    if (document.getElementById('t1').checked == true) {
      $(".t2").prop("checked", true);
      $(".t3").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      $(".t2").prop("checked", false);
      $(".t3").prop("checked", false);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: And your question is ...?

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: i think you wanna to say when you wanna to click checkbox 1 and you wanna to click all check box that you have. am i right? for example select for all check and uncheck?

Comment: Why You are passing .t2 & .t3 as class? but t2 and t3 you define as ID.
so used 
` $("#t2").prop("checked", true);
      $("#t3").prop("checked", true);`

Answer (score 0):

**Typo:** Id define by `#` in dom .you are adding `.` is define as a class

```js
function check_all() {
  if (document.getElementById('t1').checked == true) {
    $("#t2").prop("checked", true);
    $("#t3").prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $("#t2").prop("checked", false);
    $("#t3").prop("checked", false);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="t1" onchange="check_all()" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="t2" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="t3" checked>
```

For more simplified version Do like this

```js
function check_all() {
$("#t2,#t3").prop("checked", $('#t1').is(':checked'));
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="t1" onchange="check_all()" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="t2" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="t3" checked>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to missing `#` before the `id` selector int can be fixed by adding `#` instead of `.` in your selector. Anyways you can make it simpler by combining both the selector into one and the `if` condition can be replaced by using `checked` property value as the argument in [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="t1" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="t2" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="t3" checked>

<script>
  // bind change event handler or use inline onchange 
  // where pass the reference(this) as argument
  $('#t1').change(function() {
    // get both element and update property based on the 
    // current value of t1 checkbox
    $('#t2,#t3').prop('checked', this.checked);
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/> Check all</label></p>
    
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Loads of checkboxes</legend>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 1</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 2</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 3</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 4</label></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```